# Run debugger on javaFX project in android

Tags: java, android, debugging, javafx, javafxports

I am trying to rebuild an old javafx project on android. Currently I am using javafxports to do so. The problem is I can't debug it, this is how the project hierarchy looks:

[image]

The application is started from `DisplayClient`. So far I am able to log messages using the device monitor. Can you please tell me if it is possible to attach a debugger and if it is how? If any further information is needed I would be happy to give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily attach a debugger to your IntelliJ IDE while running your app on an Android device.

To debug a JavaFXPorts/Gluon Mobile that you have created using the Gluon plugin for your IDE (NetBeans, IntelliJ or Eclipse), and that you have deployed to the Android device, follow these steps:

**1. Create the JavaFX mobile app from your IDE**

For that you can use the Gluon plugin for your IDE. Use one of the built-in templates to create your project or go and use one of the many samples available here.

Let's say you use the Single View project. Provide a name and run the app

[image]

**2. Create the apk**

Run the task from the Gradle View `Tasks->other->AndroidInstall` to create the apk (or on command line run ./gradlew android).

**3. Open the app on your device**

Make sure the app works on your device, and don't close it.

**4. Open Android Device Monitor**

Go to `<android sdk>/tools` and run `monitor`. On the left, on top you should see the device, and a list of processes. Find your app package name there, select it and see the port it is using for the app (8600).

[image: Android Monitor]

**5. Attach the debugger on your IDE**

Finally, go back to your IDE, and attach the remote debugger, with localhost and 8600 port. For the IntelliJ IDE, go to `Run->Edit Configurations...`, on the upper left click `+`, select the Remote option, and provide a name (`remote debugger`), and the port:

[image: Remote debugger]

**6. Run the debugger on your IDE**

Click ok to save, add some breakpoint to your code, and now run the debugger.

In this case, I have a breakpoint in the button event handler, so when I click on it, the app halts at the breakpoint:

[image: debugging Android]