# How to configure USB Debugging for Android for a Gluon-mobile app in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, gluon-mobile, usb-debugging

I tried to configure USB Debugging for Android in Eclipse (for a Gluon-mobile application) similar to the steps described in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970567/run-debugger-on-javafx-project-in-android).
As step 5 I defined in Eclipse->Run->Debug Configurations...->Remote Java Application
[image]

When I start debugging with this config, I get

```
Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect
```

I see the device using `adb devices` and the port in the `monitor`.
USB debugging is enabled on the android device.

So what am I doing wrong or what is missing ?

**EDIT**
Meanwhile I found out that if the monitor is kept running then the debugging via Eclipse works! 
But is it really the `monitor` that needs to be running or is `adb` sufficient and what are the command line options for adb to enable the debugging with Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, monitor should be running for the port to be open.